# How to make a ruby gem read an initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a gem for ruby on rails that depends on an initializer. I have `config/initializers/pi.rb` with:

```
PI_KEY = 'my key'
PI_SECRET = 'my secret'
```

and in the gem's `lib/pi.rb` I'd like to have:

```
module Pi
  HEADERS = {
    'X-Auth-Key' => ::PI_KEY
    'X-Auth-Secret' => ::PI_SECRET
  }
end
```

but PI_KEY is undefined at the time the gem loads. `Rails.root` is also undefined at that time, so I can't just `require` the initializer. So how would I pass config to my gem from a rails initializer?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this for example:

in your `lib/pi.rb`:

```
module Pi
  class << self
    mattr_accessor :key, :secret
  end

  def self.configure(&block)
    yield self
  end
end
```

then in the application's `config/initializers/pi.rb`:

```
Pi.configure do |config|
  config.key = 'some key'
  config.secret = 'I am Batman'
end
```

Comment: I think the `mattr_accessor` line belongs just inside the class, instead of within the `class << self` block